# web.config - forward full path with parameter

Tags: angular, iis

I am trying to have direct links, so users can open items. The idea is simple - they can go directly to:

page/details_on_item/123

I am using the signin page, as the guard would simply take me there. My idea is to go to the signin page and handle the ID there.
Anyway, this does not matter for now, as I do not even get that far.

For this I need a change in the web.config:

```
        <rule name="signin Route" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^signin(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
        </rule>
```

This will see the "signin/123" and go to the expected index.html file, but routing will fail and go to my default page.
The reason is, that the path provided to the angular code is only the ID, hence "123".

The router has nothing to work on and defaults to "**".

I get this by displaying the activatedRoute.snapshot.url

If I open say page/signin/signin -> it will actually open signin as it scraps "signin/" and continues with the second signin, which the router can handle.

To my understanding my routing (below) is correct, but I need to pass the entire path to the angular router.

1. How do I change my rule to pass the entire path?
2. Is this the right way?

My routing looks as follows:

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'signin/:id',
    component: SigninComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Login',
      subtitle: ''
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'signin',
    component: SigninComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Login',
      subtitle: ''
    }
  },
//more
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: NotFoundComponent,
    data: { title: '404' }
  }
];
```

Comment: What you want to do is store that page url somewhere before you redirect your user to the sign in page. Once the user sign in you can retrieve that url value and redirect. Since you are using guard that's one place you can do it.

Comment: @penleychan, I understand your idea, but that does still not answer my question. If I open page/item/123, then I still need to get the whole "item/123" for my router to parse "item". Only At that moment when I actually get there I can look at what I can do at the guard. Right now I only get "123" and my router cannot parse that

Comment: What about change the url to use query string. For example page?item=123. Router can get item=123 after rewriting.

Comment: @BruceZhang, this worked. I got the same idea this morning

Comment: add another route to your angular: with path `signin/:type/:id` that goes before all other signin paths

Comment: @Stavm, this still gives me the issue of having 2 different links, so that does not really solve my problem, just changes the shape of it