# Modify URL on copy (-paste)

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to modify the url on copy from an angular project.

When the user selects URL and copy (like ctrl+c), it is

```
page/item/123
```

I need to modify that to

```
page/item?id=123
```

How can I do that?

Reason: I could not make the web.config work to pass the full path (item/123), so angular cannot parse what is not there.

However, I can make item?id=.... work, so it opens "item" and there I can get the query parameter.

Added: in the comments it was suggested to do it one way/the right way only and I agree - but I am here because my original problem cannot be solved: [web.config - forward full path with parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69946075/web-config-forward-full-path-with-parameter)

How to make rules work with parameters and pass the full path for parsing

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just expose that alternative URL then?

Comment: please don't go there. you're trying to solve a problem that shouldn't exist. your `web.config` needs to return the `index.html` file on every deep route linking. to do so you  need to make sure you have `UrlRewrite` installed on your IIS machine and simply add the snippet for web.config as shown on Angular docs: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration

Comment: @Stavm, I dont want to go there. I am going there becuase I have no there way. The reason is my previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69946075/web-config-forward-full-path-with-parameter
I can still not make that work, so if I cannot go the direct way, then I have to use the back door. Nobody replied to my previous post, so I assume that is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how it can be done:

html

```
<div (copy)="handleCopy($event)">page/item/1234</div>
```

ts

```
handleCopy(event: ClipboardEvent) {
  event.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', 
  document.getSelection().toString().replace(/\/(?=[^\/]*$)/, "?id="));
  event.preventDefault();
}
```